# Delphi Spinedit: Get the previous value

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

Lets say I have a Spinedit on my Form.

The current Value of the Spinedit is e.g 5

When the user clicks on the SpinButton the next Value could be

4 or 6.

In the onChange event

I can get the new Value

4 or 6

but I need to know also the old Value

5

How can I get the previous value 5 in Delphi?

I need to know the old and the new Value

Comment: I don't see any way to do this directly, but you could easily store the previous value yourself at the end of the OnChange event. You would also need to initialise the variable at startup.

Comment: You can subclass the TSpinEdit control, and add this feature yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the previous value in a variable at the end of the OnChange event and at startup as below.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Samples.Spin;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SpinEdit1: TSpinEdit;
    procedure SpinEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FSpinPrev : Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSpinPrev := SpinEdit1.Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.SpinEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SpinEdit1.Value > FSpinPrev then Caption := 'Increasing'
                                 else Caption := 'Decreasing';

  FSpinPrev := SpinEdit1.Value;
end;

end.
```

Comment: If you don't want to declare a separate variable, you can use as storage the general purpose `Tag: NativeInt` that all components have